# Waiting for reply in Socket Programming

Tags: java, sockets

I am opening and Socket connection and then I need to reply for the result from the server before moving forward.

```
While(true)
{
Receive message from Client
Process message.
Send query to client .
//wait for message
Receive the result from client.
}
```

But when the client replies, the message is received at step 1 but I need to receive it at step 4. I am not able to understand how to program it. I have basic server and client code ready. Can somebody just point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

```
While(true)
{
//wait for message - you should receive message in one point
Receive message from Client
Process message.
if (message==1) Send query to client .
if (message==2) This is result from client

}
```

upd

Not very clear your architecture, but you'll always receive messages on first step. Maybe you need to use blocking call or another solution. Eg

```
3 step:
Send query to client.
wait() // blocking call - waiting result

1 step:
if (message==2) //This is result from client
pass reply to 3 step(another thread)
```

Comment: My messages have a type, but step 1 is on a different thread. So that thread keeps on running , and keeps accepting the messages. So the client reply from Step 3 is received on that thread. Where as I want this reply specifically to step 3. I am sorry if my question was not clear.

Answer (score -1):

> the message is received at step 1 but I need to receive it at step 4.

So do that.

> I am not able to understand how to program it

Program step 4 the same way you programmed step 1.

Comment: I can, but step 1 is on a different thread. So that thread keeps on running , and keeps accepting the messages. So the client reply from Step 3 is received on that thread. Where as I want this reply specifically to step 3. I am sorry if my question was not clear.

Comment: So you can't do it then. You've painted yourself into a corner.

Comment: Guess you are right. will try a new approach then. Thanks